# Opening remote database using getDatabase()

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

My Lotus network contains multiple Lotus Domino servers (each organizational unit has its own server). I am trying to connect to Server_A and then obtain `names.nsf` from Server_B using `getDatabase()`:

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession("Server_A_IP:63148", superuser, pass);

Database names = session.getDatabase("CN=Server_B/O=Organization", "names.nsf");
```

Error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" NotesException: Database CN=Server_B/O=Organization!!names.nsf has not been opened yet
    at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHelper.read(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHolder._read(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.corba._IDatabaseStub.searchU(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.Database.search(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.Database.search(Unknown Source)
```

Opening `names.nsf` using `session.getDatabase(null, "names.nsf");` is working fine.

Comment: Did you fill out "Trusted Servers" in configuration document of Server_B?

Comment: Thank you Torsten. After entering Server_A name in Trusted Servers column of Server_B configuration document - the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

NotesFactory.createSession("Server_A_IP:63148", superuser, pass);

-> NotesFactory.createSession("Server_A_IP", superuser, pass);

You don't need the Port #

You can look at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_EXAMPLE_REGISTERNEWUSER_METHOD_JAVA.html

you should also test your session isn't a null object... 
if (session != null){

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://johnjardin.ukuvuma.co.za/2013/10/08/connect-to-a-notes-database-on-a-remote-domino-server-via-ssjs/):

> The reason the connection fails, is because Server1/ACME is not listed
>   as a Trust Server in Server2/ACME’s Server Document in the Domino
>   Directory.

And the solution:

> To resolve this issue is simple. The difficult part was finding the
>   problem. If you have access to the Domino Directory on Server2/ACME,
>   do the following:
>
> - Open the Domino Directory (Server Address Book) on Server2/ACME.
> - Under “Configuration”, click “Servers”, then click on “All Server Documents”.
> - Double click on the Server Document you want your code to connect to. (Server2/ACME in this example)
> - Under the Security Tab, in the bottom left section, there is a field called “Trusted Servers”.
> - In my scenario, this field is empty. Following this example, I would add “Server1/ACME” to this field.

**EDIT:** I have just seen that the solution was in the comments too. Anyway, I'm going to leave this steps here, just in case it be useful for someone.